# Automatic date in word shouldn't update after the document is saved

Tags: ms-word

Is possible to make a MS Word (2016) template which automatically adds the date, but doesn't update the date after the document is saved?

I can add a date field to the template: menu Insert>Date&Time, checking "Update automatically", and save it as a template, but if I create a document with that template, and I edit it another day, the date is updated, and I need the creation date to persist.

Comment: Try using the `CreateDate` field code. That will be static until/unless the document is saved using SaveAs.

Comment: @Thank you. Write it as answer, to mark it as the answer.

Comment: Glad it worked for you :-) This is actually more an end-user topic - Stack Overflow is for programming. So I'm going to nominate the question to be closed, rather than post it as an Answer.